# HAProxy redirecting

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I'm trying to get HAProxy to redirect to the right URI's in case the requested URI is non-www or non-https. The problem I'm encoutering is that it redirects as soon as it hits a line, resulting in multiple redirects.

This is my configuration:

```
*snip*

frontend traffic-in
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certificate.bundled.pem
    reqrep ^(.*)[^/]$ \1/
    redirect prefix https://www.example.com 301 if { hdr(host) -i beste.nl } 
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

*snip*
```

If I would go to http://example.com, it would first redirect me to http://example.com/, followed by https://www.example.com.

I want it to redirect me once, not several times as this would hurt our Google ranking.

How can I redirect the request to a URI with the trailing slash AND ssl?

Answer (score 1):

If you split out a http frontend it might simplify things

```
frontend http_in
  bind *:80
  redirect prefix https://www.example.com code 301

frontend https_in
  all www.example.com hdr_sub(host) www.example.com
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certificate.bundled.pem
  redirect prefix https://www.example.com code 301 if !www.example.com
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 frontend definition, like this:

```
frontend http
    bind *:80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certificate.bundled.pem
    #-------------------------
    # todo: use backends here
    #-------------------------

frontend www
    bind *:80
    acl has_www hdr_beg(host) -i www.
    http-request add-header X-Host-Redirect yes if !has_www
    redirect code 301 prefix //www.example.com if !has_www
```

**Result:** http://example.com   **>>**   https://www.example.com